# Java array of objects with array issue

Tags: java, arrays, variables, object

Been working on this for a couple of hours so thought I'd ask, When I create an array of this object the memory array which is given a random input causes the rest of the array to have the same output: see code below.

Bee Class:

```
private class Bee{
    private int status;
    private float[] memory;
    private double quality;
    private int visits;

    private Bee(int status, float[] memory, double quality, int visits){
        this.status = status;
        this.memory = memory;
        this.quality = quality;
        this.visits = visits;
    }
}
```

The individual bees quality when printed are different yet their memory stay all the same.

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.bees.length; i++){
    System.out.println(this.bees[i].memory[0]+" "+this.bees[i].memory[1]);
    System.out.println(this.bees[i].quality);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
3.4968524 8.354554
1581.5435920638447
3.4968524 8.354554
82.46318172154176
3.4968524 8.354554
66.25267691464408
```

I don't understand why the quality is working but not the memory?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalNumberbees; i++){
    int beestatus;

    if(i < numberInactive){
         beestatus = 0;//inactive
         indexesOfInactivebees[i] = i;

    } else if(i < (numberInactive + numberScout)){
         beestatus = 2;//scout

    } else{
         beestatus = 1;//active
    }

    float[] randomMemory = GenerateRandomMemory();
    this.bees[i] = new Bee(beestatus, randomMemory, MeasureQuality(randomMemory), 0);
}

private float[] GenerateRandomMemory(){
    float[] result = new float[this.functionData.vars.length];
    result = this.functionData.vars;

    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        float r1 = new Random().nextFloat()*10;
        result[i] = r1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the GenerateRandomClass and the rest of the code the initialises the bees.

Comment: Please post GenerateRandomMemory and MeasureQuality.

Comment: do you use the same array float[] randomMemory for all the Bee objects?

Answer (score 0):

`GenerateRandomMemory()` outputs the same instance of float array. Check it or post its source code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `randomMemory` array is initialized only once. either you are calling `GenerateRandomMemory()` before the loop or it returns the same reference every time it's called.

Comment: I don't think it is the case, since `quality` is between different objects differs. In order for that to be correct, `MeasureQuality()` should provide non-deterministic, or at least varying result each run.

Comment: We cannot clarify this unless he provides us the whole relevant code instead of this shortened version.